# Telegraf drop a tag from a specific measurement

Tags: telegraf

Is it possible in telegraf using a processor to drop a tag from a measurement?

Using the cisco_telemetry plugin that takes in series and within one of the measurements not the whole plugin I want to only keep one tag.
I tried using the [tag_limit](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/plugins/processors/tag_limit/README.md) processor but it didn't work. The current measurement "Cisco-IOS-XR-procfind-oper:proc-distribution/nodes/node/process/pid/filter-type" has two tags "pid" and "proc_name" each contain around 10000 values. I only want to keep "proc_name" and drop "pid" from this measurement. Should the tag_limit processor work for this? Version 1.23

```html
[[processors.tag_limit]]
  namepass = ["Cisco-IOS-XR-procfind-oper:proc-distribution/nodes/node/process/pid/filter-type"]
  ## Maximum number of tags to preserve
  limit = 1

  ## List of tags to preferentially preserve
  keep = ["proc_name"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> within one of the measurements

I would probably use a starlark processor then. Use namepass as you have done, and then remove the specific tag.

```
[[processors.starlark]]
  namepass = ["Cisco-IOS-XR-procfind-oper:proc-distribution/nodes/node/process/pid/filter-type"]
  source = '''
def apply(metric):
    metric.tags.pop("pid")
    return metric
'''
```

For users looking to do this to an entire measurement, they can drop tags from a measurement with [metric modifiers](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/CONFIGURATION.md#metric-filtering). Specifically, you are looking for `tagexclude`, which will remove tags from a measurement matching those patterns. This way, you do not even need to use a processor and can add this directly to the end of your input:

```
[[inputs.cisco_telemetry]]
  <connection details>
  tagexclude = ["pid"]
```

Comment: this was perfect. The starlink processor did the trick. thanks